# How To Make Java Annotations Useful

Tags: java, annotations

In a project that I'm working on, I would like to have a custom annotation that warns users that this specific method should be called from another thread. I've called it `@ThreadNeeded`, and I want to achieve the effect of having the compiler warn the user if the method called would be on the main thread. How can I achieve this? I have looked into many guides on Annotations, but none of them actually give a way to make use of them other than just marking the `ElementType` with the annotation. Here is the source of the annotation I have so far

```
/**
 * An annotation that signifies that this method needs to be run inside a background thread.
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ThreadNeeded {

}
```

And here is an example usage

```
    @Nullable
    @ThreadNeeded
    public SonyCamera build(){
        try {
            send();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return null;
        }
        return camera;
    }

    private void send() throws Exception {
        final byte[] ssdpreqb = SSDP_REQUEST.getBytes();
        DatagramSocket socket;
        DatagramPacket recieve, packet;
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetSocketAddress isad = new InetSocketAddress(SSDP_ADDRESS, SSDP_PORT);
        packet = new DatagramPacket(ssdpreqb, ssdpreqb.length, isad);
        socket.send(packet);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        socket.send(packet);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        socket.send(packet);

        boolean searching = true;
        byte[] array = new byte[1024];
        while(searching) {
            recieve = new DatagramPacket(array, array.length);
            socket.setSoTimeout(SSDP_TIMEOUT);
            socket.receive(recieve);
            String replyMessage = new String(recieve.getData(), 0, recieve.getLength(), "UTF-8");
            String ddusn = SSDPClient.findParamaterValue(replyMessage, "USN");
            String location = SSDPClient.findParamaterValue(replyMessage, "LOCATION");
            camera.location = location;
            camera.usn = ddusn;
            fetch(location);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The compiler has no means of knowing what thread this code will be executed on. It's not possible to do what you want at compile-time. At run-time you could use AOP to intercept methods annotated by @ThreadNeeded and do whatever you need. If you absolutely need this code to run on another thread, why don't you just write it as another thread?

Comment: Annotations are not the correct way to do this.  Write javadoc for your method and explain clearly the threads in which it may and may not run.  For examples, see [EventQueue.invokeAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) and [GraphicsContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to process annotations while compiling sources you should write annotation processor and instruct `javac`to use them.

Here is some kind of tutorial: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-annotation-processors.html

Though I'm not sure you can detect mentioned threading issues at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

The [GUI Effect Checker](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#guieffect-checker) may do what you need.  The below is taken from [its documentation](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#guieffect-checker):

One of the most prevalent GUI-related bugs is invalid UI update or invalid thread access: accessing the UI directly from a background thread.

The GUI Effect Checker solves this problem. 
The GUI Effect Checker ensures that only the UI thread accesses UI objects. This prevents GUI errors such as invalid UI update and invalid thread access.

The programmer annotates each method to indicate whether:

- It accesses no UI elements (and may run on any thread); such a method is said to have the “safe effect”.
- It may access UI elements (and must run on the UI thread); such a method is said to have the “UI effect”.

At compile time, the GUI Effect Checker issues errors in the following cases:

- A @UIEffect method is invoked by a @SafeEffect method.
- Method declarations violate subtyping restrictions: a supertype declares a @SafeEffect method, and a subtype annotates an overriding version as @UIEffect.